# --ionic2 rc0-- How to show consolelog in ios. my app move on device.not emulator

Tags: ios, angular, logging, ionic2, device

How to show console log in iOS.

I tried `ionic build ios --consolelogs` command,
but I can show console log.
My app move on device.
Please ask me how to show console log.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the flag to the build step, add it to the run.

`ionic run --livereload --consolelogs`